# I'm trying to use Arquillian smart testing lib but without success

Tags: maven-3, jboss-arquillian

I'm using:

- Arquillian 0.0.10
- Maven 3.6.3
- Surefire 3.3.3-M5
- JUnit 5.7.0

I have created the extension file on my project base: "./.mvn/extensions.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extensions>
  <extension>
    <groupId>org.arquillian.smart.testing</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-lifecycle-extension</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.10</version>
  </extension>
</extensions>
```

When I execute the following command:

```
mvn clean test -Dsmart.testing.mode="selecting" -Dsmart.testing="new" -Dscm.last.changes=1
```

I get the debug messages of the plugin, and the target file is generated however all tests are runned and in an arbitrary order.

On the documentation it is referred to execute the following command on project base folder:

```
curl -sSL https://git.io/v5jy6 | bash
```

But when o do that I receive the following error:

```
.Version 3.6.3 is not supported.
```

Can anyone help me find the error or an alternative extension/plugin that allow me to filter and order unit tests by changes?

Comment: Could you please open an issue on GitHub? I will be happy to have a look.

Comment: Sure I'll do that. Thanks @bartosz.majsak

Comment: I created the following issue: [link](https://github.com/arquillian/smart-testing/issues/451)